# A good place for something or to do something?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, grammaticality

A quick and simple question on which construction to use. 
Would a native speaker say:

- This is a good place for swimming.

Or

- This is a good place to swim (in).

Another example:

- Do you know any good places for exercise?

Or

- Do you know any good places to exercise?

I know that 'a place for...' is a proper phrase, but most examples I could find are followed by a pronoun. E.g. I will find a nice place for YOU to stay at.

So, which types of construction is correct? If both of them are grammatically okay, which one is more common

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample sentences are correct and both versions get used often.

> This is a good place for swimming.
>   Do you know any good places for exercising?
>
> This is a good place to swim (at).
>   Do you know any good places to exercise?