# "XYZ is a website to improve English (on)" VS "XYZ is a good website to improve English (on)"

Tags: word-usage, prepositional-phrases, to-infinitive, for

I am used to sentences like

- "XYZ is a [good website to improve](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22good%20website%20to%20improve%22&hl=en&sxsrf=APwXEde9c4iGKdGMTbMxGhsyb7VYb5k7KA%3A1682798792044&ei=yHhNZLyjAsOUxc8PuKS5iAs&ved=0ahUKEwi8p-mB8s_-AhVDSvEDHThSDrEQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22good%20website%20to%20improve%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIICAAQigUQhgM6BwgjEOoCECc6BwgjEIoFECc6BAgjECc6DQguEIoFEMcBENEDEEM6CAgAEIoFEJECOgcIABCKBRBDOgUIABCABDoLCC4QgAQQxwEQ0QM6BwguEIoFEEM6CgguEIoFENQCEEM6BQguEIAEOhgILhCKBRDUAhBDEJcFENwEEN4EEOAEGAE6CAguEIAEENQCOgcIABCABBAKOhMILhCABBCXBRDcBBDeBBDgBBgBOgUIIRCgAToECCEQFToICCEQFhAeEB06CAgAEBYQHhAPSgQIQRgAUABYw1tghmJoAXABeACAAcgBiAGXE5IBBjE5LjUuMZgBAKABAbABCsABAdoBBggBEAEYFA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) your English (on)"
- "XYZ is a great camera to film movies"
- "XYZ is an [amazing ball to play](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22amazing%20ball%20to%20play%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sxsrf=APwXEdeDSt6KYqFUFYdYAPq8vI9Q2ts30g%3A1682798479489&ei=j3dNZKWzHYGQxc8PgPqFiAE&ved=0ahUKEwjltuTs8M_-AhUBSPEDHQB9AREQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22amazing%20ball%20to%20play%E2%80%9D&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAE6CQgAEAgQHhCwAzoOCAAQCBAeEPEEELADEAo6CwgAEAgQHhAPELADOgsIABCKBRCGAxCwAzoHCCEQoAEQCkoECEEYAVCVBljjE2CyGWgBcAB4AIABe4gB5QOSAQM0LjGYAQCgAQHIAQbAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) street basketball (with)" etc.

I wonder if we can still use **"to"** instead of **"for"** when we don't use an adjective.
Can we say these sentences:

- XYZ is a website to improve your English (on).
- XYZ is a camera to film movies.
- XYZ is a ball to play street basketball (with).

Or do we have to say these instead:

- XYZ is a website for improving your English (on).
- XYZ is a camera for filming movies.
- XYZ is a ball for playing street basketball (with).

Using **"to"** sounds sort of off to me when there is no adjective before the noun like in "good camera," "good website" etc.

Comment: I took the opportunity of adding links so no one will ask "what does your research show"? Instances of "a good camera to film" are rare, most results have "best camera to X"

Comment: You are mis-using the to-infinitive.  for improving your English//for filming movies//for playing street basketball are correct.

Comment: Peter says we can say *"This is a good place to swim (at),"*
*"Do you know any good places to exercise?"* etc. So can we use **"to"** this way only with **"places"**? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117010/a-good-place-for-something-or-to-do-something

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't understand why you exactly changed the adjectives.

Comment: to show a variety of instances where  other adjectives can be used. I changed two adjectives out of three but if you dislike the edit, and feel it is distracting, you can rollback. But that will also remove the relevant links I added.

Comment: Here are the rules for the to infinitive: https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/how-do-you-use-the-to-infinitive-in-english

Comment: @Lambie None of those rules include the usage in sentences like "This is a good place to eat." And it doesn't cover the idiomatic usage of the preposition.

Comment: Yes, this is the same structure:  *It was a good idea to stop here*. The preposition "on" in your examples are not idiomatic. One doesn't improve one's English on a website or even on anything really. I improved my English **when on holiday in Scotland**. I improved my English doing exercises from or on that website.